# how to use window.crypto.signText?

Tags: javascript, firefox, pkcs#11

i want to sign in Mozilla Firefox using a smart card. is there any java script code, running in Mozilla Firefox, where we can use `window.crypto.signText` to sign some text. 
should we use addon or extension to do this task. i heard that `crypto api's` and `window.crypto.signtext` is disabled from Firefox version 33. Is there any alternative for signing done in Mozilla Firefox?